# Some links not opening in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$('div#content a').attr('target', 'forceToIframeWindow');

$(document).on("click", 'div#content a', function(){
 var thisSrc = $(this).attr("href");
 $(document.body).append(
 $('<iframe />').attr({
  "name":"forceToIframeWindow", 
  "src":thisSrc
 }))
});
```

DOM looks like this and here are links that work:

```
<p><a href="http://example.com" target="forceToIframeWindow">Example</a></p>
```

and links that don't work:

```
<p><a href="http://example.com" target="forceToIframeWindow"><img src="test.jpg"></a></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent the default behavior of a link you should use the `preventDefault` method

```
$(document).on('click', 'div#content a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Stops the default execution of a link. Which normally is to open in a new window
    var thisSrc = $(this).attr("href");
    $(document.body).append(
        $('<iframe />').attr({
            "name":"forceToIframeWindow", 
            "src":thisSrc   
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: This works. I found out that just adding return false works also.